# Bizzare type inference limitation - multiple type params

Tags: scala, type-inference

Why does this not compile?

```
trait Lol[A, SA] {
  def flatMap[B, SB](f: A => Lol[B, SB]): Lol[B, SB] = ???
}

val p1: Lol[Int, String] = ???
val p2: Lol[Double, Nothing] = ???

val p5 = p1.flatMap(_ => p2)
```

Result:

```
found   : Int => Lol[Double,Nothing]
required: Int => Lol[Double,SB]
   val p5 = p1.flatMap(_ => p2)
                         ^
```

Things start to compile when either:

- type params of `flatMap` invocation are explicit
- `SA` is covariant (wtf?)
- some other type than `Nothing` is used in `p2` (e.g. `Null`)
- `SB` does not occur in return type of `flatMap` or occurs in covariant position of that return type (e.g. return type is `Option[SB]`)

The above workarounds are however not acceptable for me.

Comment: Why is variance annotation no option for you? Usually it's a good idea to use variance where possible. Using `Nothing` most of the time only makes sense under variance.

Comment: @0__ `SA` simply can't be covariant given the full API (not shown here). However - you are right about the `Nothing` - if `SA` is not covariant, I can probably make up my own special type instead of using `Nothing`

Comment: Nevertheless, this error is still ridiculously bizzare and smells of a bug.

Comment: It might be a bug. Probably `Nothing` is handled specially by scalac here as the assumption that inference had failed. If no one answers, I suggest to open a bug at https://issues.scala-lang.org/

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@retronym's commentary on [SI-9453](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9453) explains the behaviour you're seeing. Here's a workaround of sorts ...

We can synthesize a type equivalent to `Nothing` which won't cause the typer to retract the inference solution,

```
type ReallyNothing = Nothing { type T = Unit }
```

ie. `Nothing` with a dummy refinement. Now with the example of the question,

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Lol[A, SA] {
  def flatMap[B, SB](f: A => Lol[B, SB]): Lol[B, SB] = ???
}

val p1: Lol[Int, String] = ???
val p2: Lol[Double, ReallyNothing] = ???

val p5 = p1.flatMap(_ => p2)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  ... 37 elided
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to better understand your problem, it can be simplified as:

```
class Lol[A]
def foo[B](f: Lol[B]) = f
foo(new Lol[Nothing])
```

which gives you the following compilation error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Lol[Nothing]
 required: Lol[B]
Note: Nothing <: B, but class Lol is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

A possible solution is to update the snippet like that:

```
def foo[B <: Lol[_]](f: B) = f
```

Back to your original code:

```
trait Lol[A, SA] {
  def flatMap[B <: Lol[_,_]](f: A => B): B = ???
}
```